# convert object to json string after function that needs python dict

Tags: python, json

I have a python function/method that takes in a student and will show profile... i realized i need to return context as a json string. how do i do that?

```
context["student"] = db.query_dict(student_profile_sql.format(student_id=self.kwargs["student_id"])
    )[0]

appear(self.request, "Show profile", {
   "student_name": context["student"]["first_name...
})

return context  // i need to return context as json string how can i do that?
```

How can i return context as a json string?

Comment: try `json.dumps(context)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the `json` library:

```
import json
```

Then use `json.dumps`:

```
return json.dumps(context)
```

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps):

> **`json.dumps(obj, ...)`**
>
> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted `str`

Comment: I get StudentProfileView `is not JSON serializable`:\

Comment: @Modelesq How about `return json.dumps(dict(context))`?

Comment: Hmm returns a different error regarding something else. Is `dict` literally dict, or another variable of mine?

Comment: @Modelesq No, `dict` is a Python type, and calling it like a function will attempt to convert the parameter to a `dict` type, much like `int`.

Comment: kk. well i think you answered my question. More errors to tend to. Thank you :D

Comment: @Modelesq What module is that `db` class created by?

Comment: actually how do i convert `context["student"]` to json string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112325/discussion-between-modelesq-and-orangeflash81).